# how to run multiple php versions with nginx on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I watched a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jbinfo/d297fcfdb151e25a299c) on github explains how
run multiple versions of php on ubuntu 14.04 with apache.

but how can we get the same result with nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this website i think it is what you want. [How to Run Multiple Versions of PHP on One Server](http://www.sitepoint.com/run-multiple-versions-php-one-server/)

Comment: Please try to summarize external tutorials. (Links to articles invariably go stale.)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using Nginx Server:

If your different applications are in different folders,

You can try writing nested location tags and write your php configuration based on that.

For example if a sub folder having an application that needs a php 5.6 version and your root application need a php version that needs php 5.5 version then 
on your 
nginx configuration inside the location stanza of your application(say app1) put your copy and paste php execution related stanza relevant to your app.

example

```
    server{

location app1{

location  ~ \.php$ {
...
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
..
}


}

location  ~ \.php$ {
...
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
..
}

}
```

You have to install multiple php versions and configure its fpm conf to match the port address

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple PHP versions on Ubuntu without any issue. You require Multiple PHP versions if applications are built in different PHP versions like PHP 8.0 and PHP 8.1. Here, we will install PHP8.0, and PHP8.1 on the server.

1. First, we will add PPA, using the below command.

   ```
   sudo apt install software-properties-common  
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   ```
2. Run the Update Command.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install PHP 8.0 with the below command.

   ```
   sudo apt install php8.0 php8.0-fpm
   ```
4. Install PHP 8.1 with the below command.

   ```
   sudo apt install php8.1 php8.1-fpm
   ```
5. Install Nginx with the below command.

   ```
   sudo apt install nginx
   ```
6. Create 2 folders to test the website with PHP 8.0 and PHP 8.1

   ```
   echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/php80/index.php 
   echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/php81/index.php
   ```
7. We will create server blocks for both websites on Nginx.

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/php80

Insert the following content for the site with PHP 8.0

```
     # Application with PHP 8.0
     server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/php80;
        index index.php;
        server_name php80.test.com;

        location ~* \.php$ {
            # With php-fpm unix sockets
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME          $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
     }
```

8. Create a second VirtualHost configuration file to work with PHP 8.1.

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/php81

Insert the following content for the site with PHP 8.1

```
     # Application with PHP 8.1
     server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/php81;
        index index.php;
        server_name php81.test.com;

        location ~* \.php$ {
            # With php-fpm unix sockets
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME          $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
     }
```

9. Create a symbolic link for both config files under **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled** directory.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/php80 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/php81 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   ```
10. Let us restart the Nginx.

    ```
    sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
    ```
11. You can access both websites in the browser and see the different versions for each.

Comment: Or you can just install Docker nowadays and have any number of php versions with any number of Apaches, Nginxes and whatnot.

Comment: Yes, correct, @emix
But, if we want to maintain on a local server then we can follow these steps.
Thank you :-)

Comment: Everybody uses Docker in local servers nowadays.

Comment: Yes, @emix, if you have steps for Docker then you can share with us, whatever you are following.